# Can we execute testNG test cases as different services.

Tags: java, testng

I have around 200 testNG test cases can be executed through maven by and suite.xml file. But I want to convert these test cases into web service or any other similar webservice so that anybody can call any test case from there machine and will be able to know whether that particular functionality is working fine at that moment.

Comment: will the tests be executed in users' machine or your own test machine?

Comment: my own test machine

Answer (score 0):

But what if no one calls the test webservices for longer time? You won't know the state of your application, if you have any failures/regressions.
Instead, you can use

- continuous integration to run the tests automatically on every code push; see [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) for a more complete solution; or, more hacky, you can create your own cron job/demon/git hook on a server to run your tests automatically
- a maven plugin that displays the results of the last execution of the automated tests; see [Surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) for a html report on the state of the last execution of each test

Comment: These all things are already in place. But our system is very flaky and integrated with many other external systems (which are actually there test environments), and execution of all thousands of test cases every hour will be a costly solution. So we want a solution where whenever a manual tester will start their testing they can execute related automated test cases as a webservice and can decide whether to move forward or not.